# How to center text in cell? (not responding with text-align: center)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS code, is not respecting the align that I set:

```
    #addParameter{
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;

    background-image: url(../img/add.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;

    float: right;

    text-indent:-9999px;
    display: block;
}

.parameterType{
  text-align: center;
}
```

In this screen shot you can see my table

https://screencloud.net/v/oA9w

I have try margin, padding, but nothing works, the text of "parametros" column must be always center.

Edit:
This is the HTML code for my table

```
<table class="Table">
        <tr>
            <td order="name" style="height: 50px;">Nombre</td>
            <td order="area_id" >Área</td>
            <td order="cost">Costo</td>
            <td order="parameters">Parametros</td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="{{user.user_id}}">
            <td style="overflow:scroll">Mauricio Andrés González Gordillo</td>
            <td style="overflow:scroll">Sanguíneo</td>
            <td style="overflow:scroll">$300.00</td>
            <td style="overflow:scroll">
              <a href="#" class="parameterType js-open-modal" data-modal-id="edit_parameter">aaa</a>
              <a href="#" id="addParameter" class="js-open-modal" data-modal-id="add_parameter"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to post the HTML, too

Comment: Post your HTML, we can't just "guess" what you are doing. Anyway, have you tried the `line-height` property?

Comment: The icon there is the problem. It's taking up space in the cell, and affecting your heights. Until you post your HTML we won't be able to fix this icon for you. Trying to fix the text is not what you want. It's the icon that needs fixing

Comment: ok, but no icon. lol. If the icon is not supposed to be there, then you don't have a problem. Delete the css and it will be fixed

Comment: The icon must be there, is part of the UI

Comment: Great, then please, would you be so kind as to provide the icon in your HTML so we can get this answered and over with lol? This is really not supposed to be so difficult

Comment: By looking at the code I can see it is being added programmatically with Angular JS. Post the HTML from the source after the browser has added all the elements.

Comment: The icon is an svg of id="addParameter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not that the contents don't center in the middle of the cell, the problem is the margins added to the floated box next to the text, it causes the box to move from its center. The vertical align answer above works fine, you may as well consider to add a position relative to the cell, and give an absolute positioning to the box, as shown in the example

```css
.Table {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;

}

  td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
  }

.parameterType {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25px; 
}


#addParameter{
    /*
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    */
  
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    
    background-color: #ff0000;
    background-image: url(../img/add.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    
    /*
    float: right;
    */
  
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display: block;
    
    /*add this*/
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px; /*half of the box height*/
}

.parameterType{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="Table">
        <tr>
            <td order="name" style="height: 50px;">Nombre</td>
            <td order="area_id" >Área</td>
            <td order="cost">Costo</td>
            <td order="parameters">Parametros</td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="{{user.user_id}}">
            <td style="overflow:scroll">Mauricio Andrés González Gordillo</td>
            <td style="overflow:scroll">Sanguíneo</td>
            <td style="overflow:scroll">$300.00</td>
            <td style="overflow:scroll">
              <a href="#" class="parameterType js-open-modal" data-modal-id="edit_parameter">text text text text</a>
              <a href="#" id="addParameter" class="js-open-modal" data-modal-id="add_parameter"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks :D
This worked like magic and also fixed some other issues that my table had.

Comment: denada Mauricio, me alegra saberlo, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly you want the text in the table to be both horizontally and vertically centered. Just like the behavior of the table right?

You can emulate this behavior with CSS by assigning

```
display:table;
```

to a `div` like `<div class="table-container">`

and

```
display:table-cell;
```

to any `div`s inside of your table.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)'s also a nice article on the W3C on how to center all things you could want to center

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's a pretty good guess, but still a guess. He has an icon in that cell taking up space. His text is actually centered to the space left over after the icon took up some. The icon is the culprit here. Until he posts the HTML, this is not really the answer. but it is a very good guess

Answer (score 0):

```css
vertical-align:middle;

/* or */

line-height:(height of your table);
```

Comment: He has an icon in that cell that doesn't exist in other cells. Until he posts the HTML, this answer is a guess, not an answer

Comment: Furthermore, vertical-align does only work on inline-elements not on block-elements. The line-height idea only works if you have only one line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you have some stuff to fix in the CSS:

```
#addParameter {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: -15px;
}

.parameterType {
   text-align: center;
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
   padding-top:15px;
}
```

And move the icon to the HTML instead of having it in the CSS and a background image. That is messing you up more than anything. In my DEMO I am using font awesome instead of an SVG image, but if font awesome is not your cup of tea, simply replace the `<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>` for an `<img src="../img/add.svg"/>`. You should have the same results.

Since it looks like you are doing this icon programmatically with AngularJS, put it in your controller or directive and you'll have the same effect.

Here is the [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPgrqz)